# Mysql last inserted row Id

Tags: mysql

In Mysql I am inserting a row with Insert command in a table of mysql , now I want the Id of last row Inserted , I am using

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() ;
```

But it gives me 0 as output every time .
Please help me in this.

Comment: Are you executing that `SELECT` on the same connection/session as the `INSERT`?

Comment: In addition, do you have an auto-increment (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column for the id on the table? Are you sure the row was actually inserted (and the insert didn't fail with an error?)

Comment: More than just having an auto-increment column, are you having MySQL generate a value for that column or are you assigning an explicit value?

Comment: No auto incremented column I am assigning value to id column with UUID command .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` only returns values that have been auto-generated by the MySQL server for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column; when you insert a specific value, no auto-generation takes place and no value will be returned by `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

You could assign a value to `LAST_INSERT_ID` yourself:

```
INSERT INTO table (uuid) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(12345));
```

[`LAST_INSERT_ID(value)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#id1014367) assigns `value` to be returned by subsequent calls to `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, and returns that same value. Unfortunately, this only works for integer values, and will not be useful with UUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to select something that is not autogenerated by insert, but passed to it? The reason is that you are using UUID() in the insert statement. I'd suggest you first to select the UUID, and then pass it to the insert

```
SELECT @id := UUID();
INSERT INTO tablename(id, value) VALUES(@id, somevalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning autoincrement an uuid this is what you are doing wrong

autoincrement field will be inserted automatically

other than that you will be getting 0 result in LAST_INSERT_ID()

Answer (score 0):

First you have to use one auto incremented line.

if you are using php then use this method :

```
 $foo = mysql_insert_id();
```

take a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

in c# i use like this:

```
                connection.Open();
                cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO o_test(game_id, user_id, date) values(?game_id, ?uid, ?date)";
                cmd.Prepare();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?game_id", null);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?uid", words[1]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?date", words[2]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int game_id;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("newId", cmd.LastInsertedId));
                game_id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@newId"].Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all columns from the last inserted id, you can go that way:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)
```